# Simplex Method Row Operations

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

In pictures provided i understand the pivot column is column 2 and pivot row is row 3.

What I don't get is why its $0.25(4R_1 +29R_3)$ and not just $4R_1 +29R_3$.

Isn't the goal to get zeros in column 2 apart from pivot?

Thanks

[image: image 1]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it would make such a major difference.
They are just trying to zero out that entry in the first row, and the simplest way of doing that is
$$
R_1 \leftarrow R_1 + 29/4 R_3 = 4/4R_1+29/4R_3 = \frac{4R_1+29R_3}{4}
$$
They use the left-most flavor and you found the right-most simpler, ignoring the denominator since the entry is zeroed out anyhow.

I find yours more intuitive, but theirs is procedurally simpler.

Comment: ok i see, what it does is make numbers working with smaller but shouldn't have a bearing on final result. as top row would be 4 times larger. cheers mate